# how to make snapshot tags public?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is it possible to make a Snapshot public and also it's name public? Currently I'm observing that I can make snapshot public, but snapshot's tags are not visible from another account.

Answer (score 1):

A snapshot can either be:

- Private
- Private and shared with specific accounts
- Public

When you say 'name', I presume that you are referring to the Tag where `Key=Name`.

You are correct that a snapshot viewed from another account **does not include its tags**, even when exactly the same `describe-snapshots` call is issued (with only the calling account changing).

This does not appear to be a permissions issue because a user with only `ec2:DescribeSnapshots` permissions (in the same account) *is* given the tags in the response. Therefore, the absence of the tags seems related to the fact that it is a cross-account call.

**Bottom line:** You won't get the tags via a cross-account `describe-snapshots` call. You would need to assume a role in the Snapshot-owning account and run `describe-snapshots` or `describe-tags` from there.